# Convert a set of strings to a multidimensional array of parsed floats

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program where the user inputs a bunch of values in a JTextField, then another JTextField, then another, etc. i.e. each JTextField should contain its own set of values, and I need an ArrayList containing ArrayLists of these values.

My problem is that it's outputting an Arraylist that contains a set of ArrayLists, all of whom's values are null.

I will also be later be adding a 3rd dimension to it, but that should be relatively easy if I can get this to work.

Below is a simplified testing version of the method I'm trying to use:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<Float> temp = new ArrayList<>();                                  //holds each float parsed from an ArrayList of strings
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> output = new ArrayList<>();                     //holds each set of floats
    ArrayList<String> items;                                                    //the string before its parsed into floats

    String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6";                                                   //testing values

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {                                             //10 is a random testing number
        //In the real version s changes here
        items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"))); //split strings by comma accounting for the possibility of a space

        for (String b : items) {                                                //parse each number in the form of a string into a float, round it, and add it to temp
            temp.add((float)((long)Math.round(Float.valueOf(b)*10000))/10000);  
        } //End parsing loop

        output.add(temp);                                                       //put temp in output
        temp.clear();                                                           //clear temp
    } //End primary loop

    System.out.println(output);                                                 //output: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have no idea why it's outputting an array of empty arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just debug it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you keep clearing the temp arraylist.

Create the `ArrayList<Float> temp = new ArrayList<>();` inside the for loop and don't clear it.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {                                             //10 is a random testing number
    //In the real version s changes here
    items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"))); //split strings by comma accounting for the possibility of a space

    // create this inside so you have a new one for each inner list
    ArrayList<Float> temp = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (String b : items) {                                                //parse each number in the form of a string into a float, round it, and add it to temp
        temp.add((float)((long)Math.round(Float.valueOf(b)*10000))/10000);  
    } //End parsing loop

    output.add(temp);  

    // don't clear
    //temp.clear();                                                           //clear temp
} //End primary loop
```